# How to delete message on channel telegram?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I need telegram bot which can delete message in group channel
i googled it  but did not find a solution
Could you tell the library and the method for this, if you know, thank you in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete ANY messages you would need the full Telegram API, as you cannot do this from the Bot API.

The required method in Telegram API is:

```
channels.deleteMessages#84c1fd4e channel:InputChannel id:Vector<int> = messages.AffectedMessages;
```

Comment: Thanks!
One more que plz
Can I create a desktop app for manage my telegram channel or it's impossible?

Comment: very possible, just focus on the messages from channels and the functions for manipulating channels, then build theses into your custom Telegram Desktop Application. Telegram API gives you all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Telegram bot API doesn't support delete any message at this time, even in group or private chat.

I think you can try [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg), a third-party unofficial Telegram client, and use it's `delete_msg` method.

Answer (score 0):

In the bot API 3.0 the method used is "deleteMessage" with parameters chat_id and message_id
Not yet officially announced

Answer (score 0):

You may delete messages only with telegram api, not bot api. With [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) (python client for telegram API) you can do it this way:

```
client.invoke(DeleteMessagesRequest(chat, [msg.id]))
```